# Blending a color image with a greyscale image in OpenCV 2

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to blend a color (RGB) image with a greyscale image in OpenCV 2. I am currently getting runtime errors and the cause seems to be that I am using different types for each image pixel. e.g. the color image is CV_8U.
My code:

```
cv::Mat copy;
    image.copyTo(copy);
    cv::cvtColor(copy, copy, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(copy, copy, 0, 255,3 );
    addWeighted( image, 0.5f, copy, 0.5f, 0.0,image);
```

The error is in the addWeighted function. I am unsure how to blend these two images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `cvtcolor`, your grayscale image is in one channel.  Change it back to three channel after you have performed `threshold`.  So, between `threshold` and `addWeighted`, add the statement:

```
cv::cvtColor ( copy, copy, CV_GRAY2BGR );
```

Also, I am not sure what you want to achieve.  If you want to just extract the regions that are white, you are better off using the `cv::bitwise_and`.

Comment: That would work, but my intention is to blend an RGB with a greyscale

Comment: Do you want a 1 channel or 3 channel output?

Comment: I want a 3 channel output.

Comment: In that case, just convert the single channel to three channel as I suggested and your code should be OK to go.